# Pushing value to stack in Assembly: why code is using particular order

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

Recently I faced to an snippet of Assembly function code that first of all saves registers value's in stack (sets `$sp` to -12) and doing its job. But in pushing first value to stack it moves 8 units from base address and for second one 4 units and for the last one 0 unit. But I don't get that why it' pushes the first value by moving 8 units and not 4?!

```
Leaf_example: 
addi  $sp, $sp, -12 
sw     $t1, 8($sp) 
sw    $t0, 4($sp) 
sw    $s0, 0($sp) 
add  $t0, $a0, $a1 
add  $t1, $a2, $a3 
sub   $s0, $t0, $t1 
add   $v0, $s0, $zero 
lw     $s0, 0($sp) 
lw     $t0, 4($sp) 
lw     $t1, 8($sp) 
addi   $sp, $sp, 12 
jr     $ra
```

Comment: assembly doesn't indicate any specific architecture. You must tag the corresponding architecture (MIPS) here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wants 3 registers stored. One MIPS register is 32 bits = 4 bytes (memory is addressable by bytes), 3 registers stored in memory thus need (at least) 12 bytes.

The `$sp` at beginning is pointing to the "top of the stack", which is already occupied by some value, i.e. bytes at addresses `sp+0` to `sp+3` form a word value at "top of the stack".

The code does then reserve additional 12 bytes for storage of the 3 registers by doing `sp = sp - 12`. After that the memory at addresses `sp+0` to `sp+11` is sort of "free", `sp+12` to `sp+15` is the previous "top of the stack" word. This makes enough room to store three words there, at `sp+0 .. sp+3` addresses, `sp+4 .. sp+7` addresses and `sp+8 .. sp+11` addresses.

How does the code pick mapping which register lands to which stack memory area is up to the original programmer, he decided to store `t1` in the `sp+8 ... sp+11` bytes, but he could have used also the `sp+0 .. sp+3` (but that would need also the same change on the restoration code part).

There's no particular reason why you can't reserve even like 40 bytes (by `addi $sp, $sp, -40`) and use then only area at `sp+20 .. sp+31` or any other parts, or in different order, or store `t1, t0, s0` and restore them as `s1, s2, s3`, etc... you are free to write whatever legal MIPS instruction you want. Whether that makes sense, and achieves your goal is different question... So asking why first register is stored at +8 is useless, the programmer did want so.

> But I don't get that why it' pushes the first value by moving 8 units and not 4?!

```
sw    $t1, 4($sp) 
sw    $t0, 4($sp) 
sw    $s0, 0($sp)
```

This would store `t0` over the same memory where `t1` is already stored, so you would keep only `t0`. So I don't get how would you want it to use +4 for first value. Like storing `s0` at `-4`? If you would do that in your whole code, treating `$sp-4 .. $sp-1` memory area as "top of the stack", i.e. occupied by some value, and avoiding changing it by other code, then you *can* do that, and it would work. But usually MIPS assembly treats `sp+0 .. sp+3` area as "top of the stack", then storing something at `-4` would make it vulnerable to other code not aware of that, but using stack in common way, it would expect `sp-4` to be "free" for its own purpose.

---

EDIT, I noticed one more thing in OP:

> (sets `$sp` to -12)

The `addi $sp, $sp, -12` does not SET the `sp`, but adjusts it by addition, so wherever it was pointing into memory before, after `add` it will point to address 12 bytes "lower". If you would set `sp` to `-12` literally, it would use that as unsigned memory address, pointing 12 bytes ahead of end of theoretical address space possible (`0xFFFFFFF4` 32b address). Depending on your target architecture there may, and may not be any memory there and if there is, it may be used for different purpose. But that would look as pseudo ins. `li $sp, -12`. It's probably just your wording which is confused, and you understanding it correctly in head, but I'm leaving this remark here in case somebody will wonder about your original post and how that part works.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking on doing so :  `sw    $t1, 4($sp) 
sw    $t0, 8($sp) 
sw    $s0, 0($sp)`

Comment: @cupcode sure, you can.. also `sw $t1, 0($sp) sw $t0, 4($sp) sw $s0, 8($sp)`, etc... as long as you fix also the restoration code to follow the same memory structure pattern. There's nothing good or wrong about that, except on some architectures it may be a bit more performant to access memory in consecutive order (0, 4, 8) to get better cache throughput, but as you are targetting stack memory, which is very likely already in cache, there can be hardly any measurable difference between the different variants (especially not in SPIM/MARS sims, as those have unreal performance characteristics).